# choice of the norm for the error of the numerical method

Tags: pde, finite-difference

When I read books on finite differences they often end up using discrete $L^2$ norm for estimating the error as it naturally arises from weak formulation. I was wondering if people do that in Sobolev norm and when it is useful. I have not seen any at least in finite-differences book.

To be more specific look at the $$Au=f,$$ where assume $A_h$ is some approximation for $A$ and $U$ is the numerical solution for the system. Then if we plug the actual function $u$ into $A_hU=f$ and substruct we have $$A_h(u-U)=\tau$$ for $\tau$ being a local error. Thus I have an error equation $$e=A_h^{-1}\tau$$ What are the problems I am facing If I use discrete Sobolev norm? What would that be then, it should involve derivatives estimates, but can I do one for the local truncation error?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define *Sobolev norm*? The L2 norm *is* a Sobolev norm. Are you thinking of the H1 norm, for example?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the associated scalar product, but I don't know further. Please answer this question.

Comment: yes, I guess I am thinking of a discrete norm for H^1, so there should be some discretization of a continuous norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a note on the motivation to use the $L^2$-error. It is natural to estimate the error in the input of a partial differential equation in the $L^2$-norm. The mathematical motivation of this is the Gauss-Markov theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem#Generalized_least_squares_estimator

It states that, if your measurement satisfies intuitive probability laws, then a least square approximation based on measurements will provide the best approximation with high probability. This choice of norm propagates within partial differential equations, so you end with $L^2$-Sobolev norms.

Now we can use this norm, too, for the error estimates in Galerkin methods, mainly because we have no better idea how to estimate the error.

Answer (score 2):

The discrete $H^1$ norm of the error is simply $\sqrt{e^T A_h e}$, so you immediately get the equation
$$
  e^T A_h e = e^T \tau = e^T A_h^{T/2} A_h^{-1/2} \tau
$$
and thus
$$
  e^T A_h e \le \sqrt{e^T A_h e } \sqrt{\tau^T A_h^{-1} \tau}
$$
and
$$
  \|e\|_{H^1 \textrm{discrete}} = \sqrt{e^T A_h e} \le \sqrt{\tau^T A_h^{-1} \tau}
$$
You treat the term on the right as always with truncation errors.

Comment: thanks, however, I'm not sure how to proceed. For example, in the case of $L^2$ discrete norm from above I'd have: $$||e||_{L^2,d}\leq ||A^{-1}_h||_{L^2,d}||\tau||_{L^2,d}$$ Then If I could show that $|\tau|<C_1h^2$ that would imply that $||\tau||_{L^2,d}<C_2h^2$ and then with a combination of boundedness of $||A^{-1}_h||_{L^2,d}$ we have the error estimates. Now that I see the discrete Sobolev norm, I'd have to estimate $||\tau||_{H^1discrete}$ which is a vector norm? What does it mean in the finite finite difference meaning? Can I use this norm to estimate the error of Crank-Nicolson?